# Events bubbling in dart

Tags: dart, event-bubbling, dart-html

I have a layer full of pictures (children), when mouse is over layer i'd like to know mouse coordinates with respect to the parent layer and one of the pictures.
I am failing to do so. To demonstrate the problem I came up with a simple example:
1 layer with one child picture and trigger on-mouse-over event.

Consider the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
  <title>bubbles</title>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="layer" style="width:1000px; height: 500px; border: 2px solid #8AC007;">
  <img id="image" src="https://www.dartlang.org/logos/dart-logo.png" style="position:absolute; left: 100px; top:100px; width:100px; height:100px; border: 2px solid #8AC007;">   
</div>

<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
<script data-pub-inline src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and dart script:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelector("#layer").onMouseMove.listen((e)=>print("${e.target}: ${e.offset}"));
}
```

When I move mouse over the layer (not image!) I get messages: `div: Point(x,y)`, where point (`e.offset`) is given in the coordinates of the layer; when I move mouse over the image I get messages: `img: Point(x, y)` with `e.offset` given in coordinates of the image. Bou NO listener was set for image.onMouseMove.

Thus the questions:

1. What is happening? Why does image.onMouseOver event get trigerred?
2. Let's assume the answer to the previous question is that because image is an offspring of the layer. But what happens then with the event bubbling? Why does not event image.onMouseOver bubble higher in the DOM to the layer and trigger layer.onMouseOver event?

Answer (score 0):

That the event is fired when you hover `<img>` is because `<img>` is part of `<div id="layer"`, `<img>` is displayed within `<div id="layer"`. This has nothing to do with event bubbling.
There are no events when you move outside `<div id="layer"` because there is no event listener registered for `<body>`. If you register an event listener for body you get events for `<body>` `<div id="layer"` and `<img>`.
Maybe `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Ok. This answers my first question. You're right, It is not quite event bubbling, because though I've got two nested elements, only one of them (`div`) registers event handler. I, for sake of testing, added the following line `querySelector("#image").onMouseMove.listen((e)=>print("${e.target}: ${e.offset}"));` Now I would expect that when I hover the image I should get messages from the image and the layer event handlers, but the output stays exactly the same as I described above.